# Is it possible to change root shell from user?

Tags: permissions, root

I think I'am facing not so common problem. I wrote

```
chsh -s /bin/false root
```

and now I can't log in as `root`. Is there any possibility how I could log in to `root`? When I try command

```
chsh -s /bin/true root
```

I get answer that I may not change shell for `root` and of course when I try to edit the `/etc/passwd` with `nano`, I get message that I don't have permission to do that.

So is there any solution how I could log in to `root`?

Comment: `chsh -s /bin/true root` would set root's login shell to `/bin/true`. Equally useless for interactive access. You'd need to set it to `/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash` etc.

Comment: Though this is unlikely to make a big difference, what operating system is that?

Answer (score 3):

Do an:

```
ssh root@localhost /bin/bash
```

You will not get a shell prompt. However, if you type ls and press enter, you will see output. Then you can use this sed command to reset your root shell:

```
/usr/bin/sed -i -e 's|^\(root.*:\)[^:]*$|\1/bin/bash|g' /etc/passwd
```

Based on your distro, the sed command might be under /bin/sed.

Obviously this is a desperate measure.

Comment: Which operating system/SSH version does this work on? Trying on Arch Linux, OpenSSH 8.6p1, this fails with both password and public key authentication. Either the connection is just closed by the server or the authentication fails.

Comment: It is true that some distributions have root ssh access completely disabled. If the OP does not have sudo or su access to root and ssh is disabled, then the only option is reboot from a flash disk.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have added this: it doesn't specifically concern root, I observed that same behavior with both root and regular users.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way out is to boot into installation media's rescue mode and fix `/etc/passwd` that way.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo /bin/bash` should do the job. You will run `bash` with superuser privileges, so editing `/etc/passwd` or running `chsh` should not be a problem.

Comment: Problem is that sudo command don't work for my, saying that "sudo: command not found" and if I try like this->  "su root /bin/bash" then it asking for my root password and when I type it nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have sudo installed, you can easily install it and `sudo /bin/bash` should work. Any linux distro can use sudo.

Also, if you are getting a password prompt, you need to use public key authentication and then enable passwordless sudo. use this to configure that https://spinupwp.com/doc/passwordless-sudo/

You should use ssh public key authentication in this case ^^.

Comment: Hmm... can you really "easily install" sudo when root doesn't have a valid login shell?

Comment: ohh I see the problem. What linux distro? You might just have to boot off a usb and chroot into your OS. From there you can install sudo or even fix your shell problem. Sorry I miss understood your problem.